# Boostrap many new cassandras to cluster with no errors

Tags: cassandra, systemd

I have cluster about 100 nodes and it grows. I need to add 10-50 on request. As I know by default cassandra has `cassandra.consistent.rangemovement=true` this means multiple nodes can't to bootstrap in a moment.
Anyway when I add many nodes using Terraform and some kind of default configuration (using Puppet) at least 2-3 becomes UJ state and eventually only one bootstrap successfully. Earlier I used random time delay before start cassandra.service, but it doesn't work adding 10+ nodes.
I'm trying to figure out how to implement kind of "lock" for bootstrap.
I have Consul and can get kind of lock for bootstrap in KV. For instance get lock using ExecPreStart systemd feature but I can't get how to release it after bootstrap.

I'm looking for any solutions for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using Rundeck before.  Basically, we had Rundeck kick off a bash script, taking parameters about the deployment of our nodes as well as how many.

What we did, was parse the output of `nodetool status`.  We'd count the number of nodes as well as the number of `UN` indicators.  If those two numbers didn't match, we'd do a `sleep 30s` and try again.

Once those numbers matched, we knew that it was safe to add another node.  The total operation could take a while to add all nodes, but it worked.